# Type-safe localized text messages

Tags: java, spring, internationalization

I would like to use a type-safe facade for `ResourceBundle` and corresponding property files like this:

```
@MessageBundle
@MessageContextConfig(messageSource = "com.example.myproject.auth")
public interface AuthMessages {

    String invalidCredentials();

    String passwordTooShort(int minNumChars);
}
```

The idea is that a Spring bean implementing this interface gets automatically created by proxy magic such that invoking a method on the bean will fetch a resource value with a key corresponding to the method name from a resource bundle with base name specified by the `@MessageContextConfig` annotation.

In a CDI environment, [Apache DeltaSpike](http://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/core.html#Messagesandi18n) provides exactly this solution.

Is there any similar implementation that works with Spring out of the box?

Comment: Wrote something ourselves (just not for MessageBundles, but zk labels), it's actually not that hard to do, a simple Proxy/InvocationHandler (default java) works fine, additionally you can make the interfaces scanable via Spring and you're done. We enabled parameter names in our build, too, allowing usage of texts like "Hello {name}" from a method `String getHello(String name);`